# Java streams modifying a list of strings to keep only the substring of each string

Tags: java, regex, string, java-stream

I am trying to modify a list of strings to keep only the substring of each of them. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
List<String> paychecks = new ArrayList<>();
paychecks.add("Paycheck_Box_EMP_61299_451");
paychecks.add("Paycheck_Box_EMP_5512_221");
paychecks.add("Paycheck_Box_EMP_99993_881");
paychecks.add("Paycheck_Box_EMP_831_141");

paychecks.replaceAll(paycheck -> paycheck.subString("insert here"))
```

I've tried to write something where it says "insert here" but it throws me errors or only red lines appear, but basically I want to take the substring of the paycheck ID after EMP_ and before the next _ . So ideally it should be like this:

```
[61299, 5512, 99993, 831]
```

Update (second attempt):

```
paychecks.forEach(paycheck -> 
                      paycheck.replaceAll(paycheck, paycheck.substring(paycheck.indexOf("Paycheck_Box_"),
                         paycheck.indexOf("Paycheck_Box_" + "\\[(.*?)\\]" + "_")))))
```

Error thrown:

```
    java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 26   
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3319)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1874)
```

Comment: How married are you to using `subString()`?  It'd probably be cleaner just to use `replaceAll()` and a regexp pattern.

Comment: I'm not too married haha, but what is the regex pattern to ignore everything between 2 things?

Comment: Actually, I find it more readable to break it into two calls, one to trim the front off, and one to trim the back off, e.g.  `people.replaceAll(person -> person.replaceAll("^.*EMP_", "").replaceAll("_.*$", ""));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'm bad at writing, and even worse at reading regular expressions, so rather than trying to make the replacement efficient, I'd prioritize human readability.

Unless I'm looking at modifying a really large set of data, I'd do something like:

```
List<String> paychecks = new ArrayList<>();
paychecks.add("Paycheck_Box_EMP_61299_451");
paychecks.add("Paycheck_Box_EMP_5512_221");
paychecks.add("Paycheck_Box_EMP_99993_881");
paychecks.add("Paycheck_Box_EMP_831_141");
    

paychecks.replaceAll(person -> person
                                .replaceFirst("^Paycheck_Box_EMP_", "") // remove prefix
                                .replaceFirst("_.*$", ""));             // remove suffix

    
System.out.println(paychecks);      // [61299, 5512, 99993, 831]
```

You could further refine the prefix and suffix regexp, depending on how exactly you know what the format is going to be.

For instance, in your updated question, the prefix is always constant, so you could use a simple `replace()` call instead.  Likewise, if you know the suffix is always numberic, you could use `[0-9]*` instead of `.*`.

Comment: Oh are you basically removing everything before _EMP_ and everything after the second _?

Comment: Or in a single replacement operation, `paychecks.replaceAll(p -> p.replaceFirst("^Paycheck_Box_EMP_(\\d+)_.*", "$1"));` You could also think about whether matching the prefix is important here and decide to just extract the first number: `paychecks.replaceAll(p -> p.replaceFirst(".*?(\\d+).*", "$1"));`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the task correctly, you want to have the `#####` from `Paycheck_Box_EMP_#####_451`.

So you do not want to *replace* something, what you want is to *extract* something, right?

This should work like this:

```
List<String> paychecks = new ArrayList<>();
paychecks.add( "Paycheck_Box_EMP_61299_451" );
paychecks.add( "Paycheck_Box_EMP_5512_221" );
paychecks.add( "Paycheck_Box_EMP_99993_881" );
paychecks.add( "Paycheck_Box_EMP_831_141" );

final var pattern = Pattern.compile( "Paycheck_Box_EMP_(\\d{3,5})_\\d{3}" );
paychecks = paychecks.stream()
  .map( paycheck -> pattern.matcher( paycheck ) )
  .filter( matcher -> matcher.find() )
  .map( matcher -> group( 1 ) )
  .collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

Or when you insist in using `List.replaceAll()`:

```
List<String> paychecks = new ArrayList<>();
paychecks.add( "Paycheck_Box_EMP_61299_451" );
paychecks.add( "Paycheck_Box_EMP_5512_221" );
paychecks.add( "Paycheck_Box_EMP_99993_881" );
paychecks.add( "Paycheck_Box_EMP_831_141" );

final var pattern = Pattern.compile( "Paycheck_Box_EMP_(\\d{3,5})_\\d{3}" );
paychecks.replaceAll( paycheck -> 
{
  var matcher = pattern.matcher( paycheck );
  matcher.find();
  return matcher.group( 1 );
} );
```

Fixed the Java based on Alex Rudenko's comments.

Comment: This does not work, `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found` is thrown.  You should get the match results and map them to String via `flatMap`: `paychecks = paychecks.stream().flatMap( paycheck -> pattern.matcher( paycheck ).results().map(mr -> mr.group(1)) ).collect(Collectors.toList() );`

Comment: The problem is with Java code, not with the regexp which is fine, I guess, `Matcher::find` or `Matcher::matches` have to be invoked before calling `Matcher::group`

Comment: Got you! Common mistake here …

Comment: Reusing a prepared `Pattern` is a nice optimization, still, its use doesn’t have to be that complicated. `paychecks.replaceAll(paycheck -> pattern.matcher(paycheck).replaceFirst("$1"));` will extract the first group.

Answer (score 2):

You was almost right in your second attempt, the easiest way to do this:

```
String prefix = "Paycheck_Box_EMP_"; // or use 17 instead of prefix.length()

paychecks.replaceAll(paycheck ->
        paycheck.replaceAll(paycheck, paycheck.substring(prefix.length(), paycheck.lastIndexOf('_'))));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex, `Paycheck_Box_EMP_(\d+).*` and replace the string with group(1).

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> paychecks = new ArrayList<>();
        paychecks.add("Paycheck_Box_EMP_61299_451");
        paychecks.add("Paycheck_Box_EMP_5512_221");
        paychecks.add("Paycheck_Box_EMP_99993_881");
        paychecks.add("Paycheck_Box_EMP_831_141");

        List<String> substrs = 
                paychecks.stream()
                        .map(s -> s.replaceAll("Paycheck_Box_EMP_(\\d+).*", "$1"))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(substrs);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[61299, 5512, 99993, 831]
```

**Explanation of the regex at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/VwPI2R/1):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Try in this way:**

- **Step 1 :** Eliminate the prefix of targeted sub-string e.i **Paycheck_Box_EMP_** 61299_451
  and then temp result sub-string : 61299_451
- **Step 2 :** Eliminate the suffix of targeted sub-string e.i 61299 **_451** and final result of sub-string will be ***61299***

  paychecks.replaceAll(x-> x
  .replaceFirst("^Paycheck_Box_EMP_", "")
  .replaceFirst("_.*$", ""));